# Spartan-6 FPGA output rise/fall times

Tags: fpga, timing, spartan

I have a small VHDL project that runs on a Digilent Nexys 3 Spartan-6 board.
One of the entities of the code divides an externally received clock by factor 2. The external clock signal is not very good. It looks more like a sine wave than a rectangle but that's a different problem.
This is the VHDL code of the divider - it doesn't do much:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mems_prescaler is
port(
    aclkr    : in  std_logic;  -- 6.144 MHz
    mems_clk : out std_logic); -- 3.072 MHz
end mems_prescaler;

architecture Behavioral of mems_prescaler is
    signal output : std_logic := '0';
begin
    process(aclkr)
    begin
        if rising_edge(aclkr) then
            output <= not output;
        end if;
    end process;
    mems_clk <= output;
end Behavioral;
```

I checked the output signal on the pin mapped to mems_clk and the rise and fall times look very bad compared to what I expected. Its about 70ns each.
The "Slew Type" and "Drive Strength" settings in PlanAhead do not change this.
There is nothing connected to the PMOD pin header on the Nexys 3 board except the scope.
Can anyone give me a hint on what to try? Thanks!

Comment: Screenshot from the scope: [image](https://i.imgsafe.org/c21869f.jpg)
Yellow is the external clock that is an input to the FPGA, red is the output with the strange rise and fall times.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question yesterday.
The scope was the problem. Its impedance was too low so I had to find another probe. I see good enough rise and fall times now for what I am doing.